# How do I fix my python code to increment for the common words between two texts?

Tags: python, counter

I am writing a code to find all the common words between a keyword list and its corresponding contract type files. The keyword list words have been stored in a set and the contract words have been stored in a dictionary. I am struggling to write code that increments by one for every time a common word is found between the keyword list and in the corresponding contract type files. Right now, it only finds one instance of each of the keyword list words. I've included the whole code just in case there is something wrong with a different part and that is affecting the counter part.

```
    common_words_dict = Counter()

    for contract_type_identifier in contract_type_sets:
        if contract_type_identifier == keyword_list_identifier:
            print(f"Processing contract type: {contract_type_identifier}")

            words_for_contract_type = contract_type_sets.get(contract_type_identifier, set())

            # Check if any word in keyword list is present in cleaned_split_words
            for word in keyword_list_words:
                if word in words_for_contract_type:
                    # Check if the word is already in the dictionary, and if not, initialize it with count 0
                    if word not in common_words_dict:
                        print(f"Common word found: {word}")
                        common_words_dict[word] = 0
                    # Increment the count for the word
                    common_words_dict[word] += 1

    # Print the resulting dictionary
    print(common_words_dict)
```

Comment: What is `keyword_list_identifier`?

Comment: Loop through the words in the text. For each word, check if it's in the dictionary. If it is, increment the dictionary value. That's the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simple example, using a couple of pages from Wikipedia.

```py
import requests
import re

from collections import Counter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_a = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler'
url_b = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss'

txt_a = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_a).content, 'html.parser').get_text()
txt_b = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_b).content, 'html.parser').get_text()
```

We can count each word occurrence in each text:

```py
cnt_a = Counter(re.split(r'\W+', txt_a.lower()))
cnt_b = Counter(re.split(r'\W+', txt_b.lower()))
```

Then, for fun, let's look up *all* words in common between two texts:

```py
common = dict(sorted({
    k: (cnt_a[k], cnt_b[k]) for k in cnt_a & cnt_b
}.items(), key=lambda kv: sum(kv[1]), reverse=True))
>>> common
{'the': (596, 991),
 'of': (502, 874),
 'in': (226, 576),
 'and': (215, 365),
 'a': (191, 349),
 'to': (171, 278),
 'gauss': (4, 428),
 'euler': (336, 6),
 'his': (82, 238),
 's': (161, 123),
 'he': (81, 200),
 'with': (91, 163),
...}
```

But what if we just wanted to look up certain words?

```py
wordset = {'mathematical', 'equation', 'theorem', 'university', 'integral', 'basel'}

>>> {k: cnt_a.get(k, 0) for k in wordset}
{'equation': 18,
 'integral': 17,
 'mathematical': 49,
 'theorem': 23,
 'university': 24,
 'basel': 18}

>>> {k: cnt_b.get(k, 0) for k in wordset}
{'equation': 3,
 'integral': 6,
 'mathematical': 32,
 'theorem': 34,
 'university': 38,
 'basel': 0}
```